# How to say in English that I am going to test a given Unit from a student's book?

Tags: word-choice

What is the best way to say that a given test is on a given subject?

Can I say 'The test is on Unit 4 from your student book?

How should I rephrase it to make it sound more natural or even correct?

Comment: Are you addressing the student who will take the test?

Comment: Yes, that's the case :) I am far from being native-like in English but I do my best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your sample 'The test is on Unit 4 from your student's book' is perfectly serviceable - I would understand what you meant. To clean it just a bit, you might say:

"The test will cover the material in Unit 4 of the textbook" (assuming that by "student's book" you mean textbook.

Answer (score 1):

I think the most natural thing to say would be:

> The test is on Unit 4 from your book.

If the student has more than one book for the course (e.g. a *Student Activity Book* and some other textbook), and you aim to specify:

> The test is on Unit 4 from your *Student Book*.